# How does this code to generate a random string work?

Tags: python

How can I understand this code? I don't know why but I can't interpret this code.

```
import string
import random


def generatepass(num):
    password = ''
    for number in range(num):
        a = random.randint(1, 100)
        password += string.printable[a]

    return password

print(generatepass(4))
```

Comment: It creates a 4 character long password by choosing random characters from among the first 100 characters in `string.printable`.

Comment: note that on my system `string.printable` contains things that would be difficult to enter into most password fields, e.g. newline characters, backspace, and a few other things that are equally difficult to type.   19% of 4 character and 33% of 8 character passwords would therefore be unusable

Comment: Note that to write a good question here, if you do not understand a piece of code, narrow it down to what you do understand, and what you do not understand. Do some research, and then show it. You've received four downvotes, and they might be because readers thought you made no effort to resolve this yourself (it does not matter if you did make an effort, since any effort was not shown).

Answer (score 1):

I have written a comment on every line of this Python program explaining what it does. Please ask if you have any questions.

```
import string # imports the library for working with strings
import random # imports the library for generating random numbers


def generatepass(num): #this is a function. Think of it like a tool you can use at any time
    password = '' #This is a newly initialized variable.  It is a string. There are no characters in it.
    #Below, range is a tool which generates the numbers between 0 and the value that it is given "num"
    for number in range(num): #This is a for loop. It takes the numbers generated by range and loops through them
        a = random.randint(1, 100) # a random number between 1 and 100 is generated and assigned to the variable a
        # string.printable below is a set of all the characters which Python can print. 
        password += string.printable[a] #The printable character at location a is added to the password string

    return password # once all the numbers in range have been looped through and that number of characters added to the password, 
#then the password is returned to where the function was called. 

print(generatepass(4)) #the function is called here. The code goes and does the function and then prints the result.
```